# There is a driving problem with the Kvaser leaf

Tags: linux

When I transplant programs on embedded platforms, I encounter the problem of not being able to identify hardware devices:

1. My development environment:

- Target platform (NXP-imx6) : Ubuntu18.04 arm32 ROS1:Melodic LTS
- Original platform (Intel-i7 8700) : Ubuntu18.04 x64 ROS1:Melodic LTS

2. Use of equipment:
   The Kvaser leaf Light V2 is different from the original platform after it is connected to the target platform using USB.

   [image]

   On the original platform, after Kvaser is connected, the new device *leaf0* appears in the */dev* directory and runs normally.

   On the target platform, only the following prompts appear when connecting, and no new devices appear in */dev*.

   [image]

The solution I tried (on target platform) :

I asked the engineers of Kvaser Company, and they replied that the kernel module was not loaded. I tried to reinstall the kernel. Since the Linux version is 4.1.15, I found the corresponding kernel on the Internet.

I asked the developer of the target platform. Since the baseboard was developed by them, they believed that the error reported in the figure was not related to Kvaser equipment, but was caused by the external display.

I think it may be caused by the mismatch between the cpu core architecture and Kvaser driver, but I don't know the bottom layer, so I would like to ask for help here.

What I expecting:
Kvaser can be used normally on the target platform (in software, Leaf0 can be discovered in /dev).

Please comment if there are any details I need to add，thank you to anyone who answered this question!

Comment: did you try to execute `sudo dmesg` right after plugging in the USB device to see if the kernel recognizes the device? Also what does `lsusb` give you as output? (Always compare dev and target sytem)

Comment: I also just saw on the Kvaser website that they provide a kernel module to compile yourself - you probably have to do that instead "another" complete kernel - hardly any kernel will include that specific kernel module. Did you install the "Kvaser Linux Drivers and SDK" from https://www.kvaser.com/download/ also for your target device?

Comment: Yes i have , and i can see Kvaser in the list as lsusb output. But it didn't work

Comment: thank u for your answer ，about this URL： kvaser.com/download and "Kvaser Linux Drivers and SDK" i had successfully installed it before，I went to their company to solve the problem，but the engineer who dose the work isn't at there

Comment: but did you actually compile the kernel module also for the target platforms kernel and install it there? I would actually recommend to take the "DKMS" path, but I don't have that much experience on embedded systems with that. What I can see from the release notes on the mentioned package is that they never tested it with on an arm32 platform - good luck! ;)

Comment: oh, another question: did you copy the file "10-kvaser.rules" to the `/etc/udev/rules.d` folder on the target system? (The make of the drivers could have done that, but you should check it). Udev is the thing that will create the entries in the `/dev` folder on a plugin of the USB device.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer to this question @cyberbrain .The engineers at cyberbrain and Kvaser say they have tested it on embedded architectures from various vendors, so I think my target platform may have a problem. And I've had the pleasure of compiling the kernel.
As for the "another question" you asked, I haven't tried it yet. Thanks for your prompt, I will do it now. Thank you very much. Finally, I wish you all the best